# How do I grapple/throw in Mortal Kombat 1?

Tags: mortal-kombat-1992

I've been playing the original Mortal Kombat on a Sega Genesis and haven't figured out how to execute the grapple move where you grab your opponent and throw them behind you. On Very Hard it's fairly difficult to fight in close proximity without this move. I've had trouble finding this move on the Internet, but I know it should be possible because I've seen my opponents perform the move several times and I accidentally performed it myself once and can't remember how I did it.

Can anyone tell me how to perform the grapple/throw move in Mortal Kombat 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent [user1887158](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/187578/user1887158) providing the actual information from the manual, page 10 of the game manual states (emphasis mine):

> ### When in close quarters
>
> Additional moves used in close quarters are the knee, the head blow, and the throw. All three are highly effective, and do not require the full limb extension which is impossible in close quarters. Although these moves are potent, **they can only be used when directly adjacent to an opponent.**

Basically get in close (using the D-pad), and use the punch button (default C on the original Dreamcast controller) to throw your opponent.

[Source](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Sega_Genesis/manual/Formated/Mortal_Kombat_-_1993_-_Acclaim_Entertainment.pdf):

[image: Manual Controller picture]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get in close, push the D-Pad towards the opponent and whilst doing so, press the low punch button (or just the punch button if you are on the three button co

Answer (score -4):

Here's a link to the game manual from the original SEGA version of the game:

[http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Sega_Genesis/manual/Formated/Mortal_Kombat_-*1993*-_Acclaim_Entertainment.pdf](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Sega_Genesis/manual/Formated/Mortal_Kombat_-_1993_-_Acclaim_Entertainment.pdf)

Page 10 is titled "WHEN IN CLOSE QUARTERS."  Give it a look.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. please quote the relevant section which relates to your answer. should the link go down and be inaccessible for any reason you're answer wont be of any use to anyone